# Is it safe to set SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS on startup with VCL?

Tags: delphi, winapi, c++builder, vcl

I've found that it is recommended to call the `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)` on application startup:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode

I know that VCL code sets this mode temporarily in some functions. But it does not do this globally on application startup.

As I do not see any advantage of the default behavior, I'm considering setting it explicitly from my code. I just wonder, if VCL is designed to run in this mode. Is anyone aware of any potential problem? Any reason, why VCL does not set this mode itself?

Comment: If `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)` is the recommended behavior for all apps than Microsoft should make that the default for all new processes, instead of requiring app developers to call it explicitly, IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly fine in a VCL application to follow the MSDN advice and set SEM_ FAILCRITICALERRORS at startup.

Comment: I created two test projects, one is a package the other is an exe. I navigated to the exe's project options/packages/build with runtime packages, entered the library's name and built the bpl, then the exe. 

Then I went to bpl's source and deleted one of the methods, rebuilt bpl, ran the exe, it opened the error the dialog box. Then in the exe project I did view source and wrote `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)` before the Application Initialize method call. It still shows the message box. Where should I write this in order to handle the error manually?

Comment: What message box do you see?

Comment: The procedure entry point @Libtest@TLibTest@TestMissingProcedure$qqrv could not be located in the dynamic link library LoadedLibrary.bpl.

Comment: That's an error raised by the Delphi runtime, and so not affected by the `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` error mode.

Comment: perhaps maybe delphi runtime calls loadpackage which calls loadlibrary so if I could call seterrormode before delphi runtime does it's thing I could prevent the dialog box ?

Comment: Failures in `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` are not critical errors.

Comment: Yes, I wish my program did not get stopped by non-critical errors.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place. The Windows error mode is not relevant to your issue.